# How to feed oracle 11g schema_prod with schema_dev data

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

Can someone tell me please how to feed schema_prod with data from schema_dev please ?

I am working on oracle 11g 2 connected with labvantage ERP and before 2018, i want to transfer all data created on schema_dev to another schema_prod, that means that both schemas have the same architecture but not the same data.

schema_dev is full with more data and schema_prod is filled by only some data!

thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are about to transfer data, **data pump** might be what you're looking for: use data pump EXPORT to "unload" (export) data from SCHEMA_DEV and then import data using - what? Data pump IMPORT, of course.

Note that you'll have to create a directory (Oracle object which points to directory on a disk, usually on the database server) and grant privileges to user that is performing that action.

As you need data, you'd use CONTENT=DATA_ONLY parameter.

Here is [Data Pump Export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624) documentation, so - have a look (Import documentation is on the next page).

Alternatively, you could use **original exp and imp utilities** which can easily be run on your own computer (i.e. you don't need *directory* as with the data pump). You'd use IGNORE=YES parameter here (as import will try to create tables, but they already exist so - instruct it to ignore CREATE TABLE errors and proccede with importing data).

Original export & import documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#g1070082).

Answer (score 0):

As only data transfer is sufficient in your requirement, you also have option to use CTAS or INSERT INTO TABLE using link server to refer the source table.

Consider following example of code if you are new with inserting data taking source table through link server:

```
**Create link in target server:**
Create public link server link_name
connect to DB_USER_Source identified by password_db_user_source
using '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <<IP_HOST_SOURCE>>)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = SERVICE_NAME = <<<SID_NAME_SOURCE_MACHINE>>>)))';
or
Create public link server link_name
connect to DB_USER_Source identified by password_db_user_source
using '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <<IP_HOST_SOURCE>>)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = <<<SID_NAME_SOURCE_MACHINE>>>)))'

**Refer following query to load data from source to target, run the command in target machine:**
create table target_schema.table_name as select * from source_schema.table_name@link_name;
or
insert into target_schema.table_name select * from source_schema.table_name@link_name;

Also, you can generate above commands by following SQL query if you have large numebr of tables to transfer and run output commands in the target server:
select 'create table target_schema.' || table_name || ' as select * from source_schema.' || table_name || '@link_name;' from all_tables@link_name where owner='SOURCE_SCHEMA';
or
select 'insert into target_schema.' || table_name || ' select * from source_schema.' || table_name || '@link_name;' from all_tables@link_name where owner='SOURCE_SCHEMA';
```

Note that there are following limitations in above methods. Based on your requrements, you don't have any problem with following limitations.

- CLOB data type fields are not allowed to trasfer over the link
  server.
- Constraints are ignored

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions, i use this method and it works good even if i had 4 errors:

1- sqlplus :

```
select sid,serial# from v$session where username = 'SCHEMA_PROD';
alter system kill session ',';--this is for killing used sessions
drop user SCHEMA_prod cascade;

create user schema_prod identified by passwordXXXX
default tablespace lvsspace 
temporary tablespace temp 
quota unlimited on lvsspace 
quota unlimited on lvsidx;

grant connect, create procedure, create trigger, create table, create sequence, create type, create view to schema_prod;
```

=> exit SQLplus

2- (CTRL+C) on widnows

```
impdp system/dba schemas=shema_dev remap_schema=schema_dev:schema_prod directory=fileoutdir dumpfile=180111DEV.dmp
logfile=180111DEV.log transform=OID:n
```